# Does the "leftmost prefix rule" of Index applies to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MySQL, the leftmost prefix is applicable in the case of multi-column Index, mentioned in

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

---

Say an Index is made of (col1, col2, col3).
Combinations Eligible for Index Search:

- (col1)
- (col1, col2)
- (col1, col2, col3)

Combinations Not Eligible for Index Search:

- (col2)
- (col2, col3)
- (col3)

---

Does SQL Server uses the same rule for Index Seek mechanisms too? Is there an official document that I can refer to? I have tried searching it around but no luck :( Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server also follows similar approach for composite indexes, where only the columns from left are considered for index seek. Below is the official documentation of the same:

Index on (a,b,c) will be useful for below seek queries

- a
- a,b
- a,b,c

[Read more on Index Design practices on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#General_Design)

> Consider the order of the columns if the index will contain multiple
> columns. The column that is used in the WHERE clause in an equal to
> (=), greater than (>), less than (<), or BETWEEN search condition, or
> participates in a join, should be placed first. Additional columns
> should be ordered based on their level of distinctness, that is, from
> the most distinct to the least distinct.
>
> For example, if the index is defined as LastName, FirstName the index
> will be useful when the search criterion is WHERE LastName = 'Smith'
> or WHERE LastName = Smith AND FirstName LIKE 'J%'. However, the query
> optimizer would not use the index for a query that searched only on
> FirstName (WHERE FirstName = 'Jane')

Answer (score 7):

That rule is basically the rule for scanning b-tree indexes.

That said, there is an alternative scan method, which Oracle calls "skip scan".  This allows scanning an index on keys that are not the left-most in the index.  Some databases implement this, to a greater to lesser extent.  [Here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) is a good introduction to the topic.  I don't believe that SQL Server implements skip-scans.

Although skip-scans are powerful, their utility depends on the cardinality of the first key in the index.  If the first key has high cardinality, then they are not very effective.

Comment: Congrats on the 1MM !!!!  Wish I witnessed the big event.